# JQuery populate select element using json data

Tags: jquery

I am using this jquery to populate a select element with options:

```
$("#ticket_customer").change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "?getContactList=2&customer=" + $(this).val(),
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        var sel = $("#ticket_contact");
                        sel.empty();
                        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                          sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].sequence + '">' + data[i].forename + '</option>');
                        }

                        //$("#ticket_contact").html(data);
                        GetCustomerDetails();
                    }
                });
            });
```

the request to the URL is returning data in the following format:

```
[{"sequence":"465","forename":"first1","surname":"second1","email":"email@domain.com"},{"sequence":"465","forename":"first2","surname":"second2","email":"email2@domain.com"}]
```

but its not populating the element

Comment: I think you forgot dataType : "json"

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add dataType to specify what format you are using:

```
$("#ticket_customer").change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "?getContactList=2&customer=" + $(this).val(),
                    async: true,
                    dataType : "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var sel = $("#ticket_contact");
                        sel.empty();
                        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                          sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].sequence + '">' + data[i].forename + '</option>');
                        }

                        //$("#ticket_contact").html(data);
                        GetCustomerDetails();
                    }
                });
            });
```